# stats null in facebook insights

Tags: facebook

I've used the facebook comments box in my site for a few months.

But when I check the stats on the insights of my app, there is nothing, every data is null.

Did I forget something to activate the stats?

Thanks!

Comment: You never accept any answers... If someone answers your question and it helps you solve the problem you have to click that little check mark next to the answer.

Comment: Sorry, never is not entirely true (I checked 1 out of 3 questions that have been answered) :) I hadn't checked the last one because both answers were interesting and I'm still on that issue, but I checked it now!